# how to match regex comma only first and last only

Tags: regex

I need to match number in comma using regex but only first and last comma

my regex so far

```
/[.]*,[.]*/g
```

Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Could you provide input strings that should match and that should not match?

Comment: could you be *slightly* more specific please? I.E. a sample variable, etc

Comment: ",1,2,3,4," for example I need to replace first and last comma with whitespace to be  "1,2,3,4"

Comment: Your regex matches a comma between any number of dots.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?!,[^,]*,),|(^[^,]*?),
```

Use this.A generic solution for first and last `,`.

Replace by

```
$1<whtever u wanna replace with>
```

See demo

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/2

Comment: @muhnizar Yes the first part uses a negative lookahead stating that a `,` should not be followed by another `,`.This gets us the last `,`.Second says capture first `,` from the start.`[^,]` says capture anything other than a `,` thus enabling us to get the first `,`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
/^,|,$/
```

#### [Live preview](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6O9)

```
preg_replace("/^,|,$/", "", $input_lines);
//Output: 1,2,3,4
```

*Removed `[`, `]` after comment reading*

Comment: Why `[,]`, just use `,`

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'm weird :)

Answer (score 0):

```
,?\B,?
```

Replace with an empty string

*Input:* `,1,2,3,4,`
*Output:* `1,2,3,4`